# Home Network - Daisy Chain vs 1 Big Switch to separate ports

Tags: networking

I'm just designing up a home network where I have the opportunity to run cat6 cable around the house.

I'm unsure of which option is better out of these 2:

1:
1x 24 port switch, connected to the router, then running a single cable from each port to an individual port/faceplate within the room. So let's say I have 6 rooms, with 3 sockets in each. Each of those sockets then correspond directly to a port on the main switch.

2:
1x 6 or 8 port switch, connected to the router, then each room has it's own switch within the room, running off a single port in the room.

It seems cheaper to do 2 as smaller switches, especially non-PoE are cheap - however it does introduce wiring within the room which isn't ideal.

I also have a few cameras which currently run off PoE that I'd need to connect up. so again either the main switch has PoE ports which each camera can connect to individually, or I have a separate PoE switch that services the cameras and connects to a single port on the main switch.

Which of these is a better option? Or is there something else I need to consider? I have read that the cameras are better off being on their own network not routed through the internet as they don't need to be opened up to that (I have Blue Iris).

I'm a bit of a noob at networking so I don't really know what the best option is in terms of function, efficiency, cost and futureproofed expansion.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just to add. Is there any problem with running a PoE switch off a standard Gigabit switch? So Router -> Non-PoE switch -> PoE Switch -> Camera?

Answer (score 0):

Cabling is something that has an *initial* cost but its cheaper to do what you need at once, and not worrying about it.

> 1: 1x 24 port switch, connected to the router, then running a single cable from each port to an individual port/faceplate within the room. So let's say I have 6 rooms, with 3 sockets in each. Each of those sockets then correspond directly to a port on the main switch.

gives you more flexibility - its initially harder/more costly, but if a cable goes, you have options. Its also 'neater' than popping a switch per room. If you're going for a 24 port switch, you can get a managed one and use vlans to manage 'seperate' networks without additional network hardware.

> 2: 1x 6 or 8 port switch, connected to the router, then each room has it's own switch within the room, running off a single port in the room.

*usually* is a sign that you didn't plan that well. You might be able to use POE injectors for cameras even if you have a non POE switch - but you really are better off having all your big networking hardware in one place.

I'd recommend doing it *right* and going with the first option